# Iterating through an associative array

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get all twitter followers for a specific user with this API call

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=twitterapi,twitter&include_entities=true
```

And there is a sample output there:

```
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup
```

I am trying to get the screen name of the user by doing the following:

```
$json2=file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id='.$post.'') ; 
$accounts2 = json_decode($json2);

while( $element = each( $accounts2 ) ) {
  echo $element[ 'screen_name' ];
  echo '<br />';
}
```

where $post is all the ids (around 100) concatenated together.

The above would fail with:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 3):

Replace this line:

```
$accounts2 = json_decode($json2);
```

With this:

```
$accounts2 = json_decode($json2, true);
```

It converts it into an associative array. Because `user_id` is unique, you don't have to loop through the results, but can simply do this:

```
echo $accounts2[0]['screen_name'] . '<br />';
```

Comment: Now i am getting: Notice: Undefined index: screen_name

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
$json2=file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id='.$post.'') ; 
$accounts2 = json_decode($json2);
foreach ($accounts2 as $key => $jsons) {

             foreach($jsons as $key => $value) {

                if($key == 'screen_name'){
                 echo $value;
                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: the inner loop is unnecessary as the loop will only work if the array is associative and you might as well look up directly then

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
$json2=file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id='.$post.'') ; 
$accounts2 = json_decode($json2,true);

echo $accounts2[0]['screen_name'];
```